# Retain logging effect even after I deploy APK through "export signed application package..."

Tags: android, proguard

I realize all my logging effect (`Log.i`) disappear, when I deploy my app through APK using `Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package...`

Even after my ProGuard had commented out logging related configuration

```
#-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
#    public static *** d(...);
#    public static *** v(...);
#    public static *** i(...);
#}
```

Is there any settings I had missed out? I wish logging effect is still there, even I export my ProGuard processed as a APK file.

This is because I would like to debug some [crashing problem caused by ProGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410520/google-drive-api-doesnt-play-well-with-proguard-npe).

Comment: Can you simply temporarily raise your `Log.i()` calls to `Log.w()` or `Log.e()` instead?

Comment: Replacing `Log.i()` with `Log.w()` or `Log.e()` doesn't help much. The only different is, I create 2 APKs with and without `proguard.config=proguard-project.txt` in project.properties. Both are having `android:debuggable="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. The one with proguard enabled print out nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProGuard doesn't spontaneously remove any logging code. As the symptoms of one of your other questions today ("[keep class and keep interface in proguard doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410645/keep-class-and-keep-interface-in-proguard-doesnt-work-as-expected)") suggests, you should double-check that you're editing the correct configuration file (proguard-project.txt, as of Android SDK r20) and that you're looking at the output of a successful build.

Comment: Triple check on project.properties. Pretty sure the line `proguard.config=proguard-project.txt` is pointing to correct proguard configuration. I tried to change it to `proguard.config=xxx-proguard-project.txt`. As expected, I'm getting prompt error during "Export Signed Application Package..."