# ProGuard meets Drive API

Tags: android, proguard

My app works pretty good without ProGuard but when using it, I always get

> 403 UsageLimits, Access Not Configured

errors from the Google Drive API.

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410520/google-drive-api-doesnt-play-well-with-proguard-npe) ProGuard configuration. There are no Exceptions thrown - everything seems to work fine - just the requests fail. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the reason why it failed.
Not proguard is the issue. I genereated a SHA-Hash and entered it in the Google API Console for my app. The release version is signed with another keystore and I had to generate another SHA-Hash for this version.