# Google Drive API is not working after Proguard obfucation

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:10.0.1'
```

to implement Google Drive in my Android app. The app is working well until i obfuscate the application with Proguard. Once the application is obfuscated, while i try to enable Google Drive Backup option, the app pop-ups the account selection dialog and doesn't proceed after that.

In the debug version of the app, while i try to enable Google Drive Backup option, the app pop-ups the account selection and then proceed to Google Drive Permission dialog to access the drive files.

I have read that Google added the Proguard rule for the Google Play Services and wonder what could be the issue in my case. I have also tried the Proguard rules suggested in the following StackOverFlow threads

[Google Drive API doesn't play well with ProGuard (NPE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410520/google-drive-api-doesnt-play-well-with-proguard-npe)

[Release apk not working after enabling proguard, not able to debug too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678124/release-apk-not-working-after-enabling-proguard-not-able-to-debug-too)

[How to fix Proguard issue with Google Drive REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378671/how-to-fix-proguard-issue-with-google-drive-rest-api)

But, the provided solutions didn't work for me. Is there any new rules to be added for the latest Google Drive API to work?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25823603/5832311), you can check what gets taken away by looking at the ProGuard [output files](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html). Also based from this [blog](https://softwyer.wordpress.com/2012/10/20/android-google-drive-sdk-and-proguard/), it was definitely a Proguard problem. It was also noticed that one of the debug statements indicated that the [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) object had some obfuscated fields that were probably causing a problem. *A quick look at the class file showed that this class had some annotations and we’d seen references in Proguard to keep annotations.*

You may also check on this [thread](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API/issues/20) if it helps.